# Invoking AWS Lambda using boto3 from EMR results in ReadTimeoutError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc

I have a PySpark script running on EMR Serverless. In that script, I need to invoke a lambda. So, I use boto3 and set up the lambda client as follows:

```
self.client = Session(region_name=aws_region).client("lambda", config=Config(
            tcp_keepalive=True, read_timeout=900, connect_timeout=900, retries={"max_attempts": 0}))
```

`<my-lambda>` has a 15 minute timeout, and does nothing but sleep for `x` seconds. When `x < 350` I have no issue. But, when `x >= 350` and I use the client to invoke my AWS Lambda  `<my-lambda>` I get a series of exceptions, ultimately resulting in a `botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError` exception being raised (see bottom of post).

I believe this is due to `EMR Serverless` running on a `VPC` with a `NAT Gateway` which have [idle timeout set at 350 seconds](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/implementing-long-running-tcp-connections-within-vpc-networking/#:%7E:text=All%20of%20the%20services%20mentioned%20above%20currently%20have%20the%20idle%20timeout%20set%20at%20350%20seconds.%20When%20you%20have%20ongoing%20packet%20exchange%20over%20your%20TCP%20connections%2C%20with%20packets%20being%20sent%20in%20under%20350%20seconds%2C%20everything%20works%20as%20expected.%20See%20following%20diagram%20for%20more%20information.) resulting in an [Idle Timeout](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/implementing-long-running-tcp-connections-within-vpc-networking/#:%7E:text=services%20listed%20above.-,Idle%20timeout,potentially%20use%20resources%20while%20expecting%20a%20response%20that%20will%20never%20arrive.,-(Figure%202.%20Network). I believe this because even if `x = 350` I do not get the `ReadTimeoutError` exception until `900` seconds have passed, leading me to believe that the lambda client does not know that the connection has timed out, and is therefore waiting the full `900` seconds before raising the exception.

I would have thought that setting `tcp_keepalive=True` in the `boto3` lambda client would have fixed this issue, but apparently not. My question is, does anyone know how I can overcome the Idle Timeout another way (without a major refactor)?

Thank you in advance.

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 464, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 788, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 525, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 451, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _raise_timeout
    self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: AWSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=900)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-7bb0f490-789e-432b-8971-d22ef3b27cd8/<my_pyspark_script>.py", line 867, in <module>
    <calling_function>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 944, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 966, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 207, in _send_request
    exception,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 361, in _needs_retry
    request_dict=request_dict,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 207, in __call__
    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 285, in __call__
    attempt_number, response, caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 320, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 364, in __call__
    attempt_number, response, caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 248, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 416, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 281, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 377, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 492, in send
    raise ReadTimeoutError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/<my-lambda>"
```